# MapReduce job using up all 2TB HDFS space for small 20MB file word count analysis

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I'm performing some analysis using mapreduce. The text file is only 20MB. The configured HDFS is 1.95TB. This setup is just for learning purpose. The map reduce is written in R and using Rhipe. The job reads the file, removes stop words, counts the words, and also does some regex stuff. The replication factor is set at 1 as shows as Default replication factor in `hadoop fsck /`. However, it's using up all my resources. I think the memory is fine, but the job is stuck after 8-9 hours. When I look into each nodes using `df -h`, it tells me that the drive is 100% used on all nodes. I also tried setting up datanode in the namenode server (lack of resources), but it got used up too (I know that's a bad idea). I just don't understand how a 20MB file words extract and count use up 2TB of space. What else can I do? I also set the replication interval at 216,000, but it still using up all of the resources. The HDFS data are in `/home/data` directory. I used `du -sh` to find out which directory is the job files being stored.

I'm not sure what other information to include, so if you let me know what stats or info I should include, I'll include it right away. But right now, it just seems there's a lot of information but don't know which ones are relevant and which are not.

```
map.sentiment <- (expression({
  suppressWarnings(suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(rjson)))
  suppressWarnings(suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tm)))
  suppressWarnings(suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(stringi)))

  #read lines
  l <- unlist(map.values)
  n <- 0
  #create a numberic vector
  jText <- character()

  #create emoticon dictionary
  emos <- as.character(outer(c(":", ";", ":-", ";-"), c(")", "(", "]", "[", "D", "o", "O", "P", "p", "S", "s"),paste,sep=""))
  emos <- as.character(c(emos, ":'(", ":'-(", "^^", "=(", "=)"))
  #reps <- data.frame(seq_along(emos), emos)
  #reps[,1] <- paste("EMOTIONREPLACE", reps[,1])

  #loop to read lines for each block of map values
  for(i in 1:length(l)){ #length(l)

     textJSON <- fromJSON(unlist(map.values[i]))

     #extract number of line (n)
     n <- textJSON$n

     #extract text values from json
     jsonText.sentiment <- textJSON$text

     cleanTweets <- function(jsonText){
       #some necessary clean up
       #remove retweet entity
       jsonText <- gsub("(RT|via)((?:\\b\\W*@\\w+)+)", " ", jsonText)

       #remove @people
       jsonText <- gsub("@\\w+", " ", jsonText)

       #remove html links
       jsonText <- gsub("http\\S+\\s*", " ", jsonText)

       #remove punctuation
       jsonText <- gsub("([^a-zA-Z](')[^a-zA-Z])", " ", jsonText)
       jsonText <- gsub("(#)[^a-zA-Z0-9]"," ", jsonText)
       jsonText <- gsub("[-=]{1,4}(&gt;)|(&lt;)", "", jsonText)
       jsonText <- gsub("(&gt;)|(&lt;)","",jsonText)
       jsonText <- gsub("([-=$+^!?.|~]){1,4}", "", jsonText)

       escape_regex <- function(r){
         stri_replace_all_regex(r, "\\(|\\)|\\[|\\]", "\\\\$0")
       }

       #keep the emoticons
       regex1 <- stri_c("(", stri_c(escape_regex(emos), collapse="|"), ")")
       jsonText <- stri_replace_all_regex(jsonText, stri_c(regex1, "|\\p{P}"), " $1 ")

       sonText <- gsub('[[:digit:]]+', ' ', jsonText)

       #remove words less than lenght 2
       jsonText <- gsub("\\b[a-zA-z]{1,2}\\b"," ",jsonText)
       jsonText <- removeWords(jsonText, stopwords("en"))
       jsonText <- gsub("^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$", "", jsonText)

       jsonText <- tolower(jsonText)

       jsonText
     }


     jsonText.sentiment.clean <- cleanTweets(jsonText.sentiment) #sentiment

     jText <- c(jText, paste0(unlist(strsplit(jsonText.sentiment.clean, " ")), "@doc=", n))

     }
  lapply(jText, function(i) rhcollect(i, 1))

}))
```

Comment: Something's wrong with your code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Can you elaborate? I tested the code with subset of the data, which produced the output I needed. Are you saying there's something wrong with the code that it's creating creating too many chunks of data? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, OK, I'll add my code as an EDIT.